# Google Maps API get photo_reference from nearbysearch JSON

Tags: json, google-maps

Good Morning,

at the moment I am trying to build a website which shows exactly one photo from a nearby search in the google map API. In this example I am just trying to have an alert with the photo_reference which I will need to display the photo later but I cannot figure out how to get this photo_reference ID. This is my current not working code:

```
var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=MYAPIKEY";
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    var photo_reference = data.results[0].photos[0].photo_reference;
    alert(photo_reference);

});
```

I hope somebody out there can help me with this one.

Here is the photo_reference I am trying to get:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
 "results" : [
     {
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : -33.86879,
           "lng" : 151.194217
        }
     },
     "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
     "id" : "21a0b251c9b8392186142c798263e289fe45b4aa",
     "name" : "Rhythmboat Cruises",
     "opening_hours" : {
        "open_now" : false,
        "weekday_text" : []
     },
     "photos" : [
        {
           "height" : 467,
           "html_attributions" : [],
           "photo_reference" : "CnRnAAAAUYdlxXeaepO7jaUN863gNM1ExtUmabHALXdL1hsrpH6bWVtbXo_3ZXRz--oVGXBYnZJr8M5IMWqtLYDoUPFSNwxrJjWTRnZMPCsuEXbMOFaHNfF1xBwGEAcV-SkV0qorkv7b0jeT_CP0dMXND-H3jhIQft0a9rAxYMhQob9VALAPSRoUrRCcxHa7DdVxbxd8FwOH7UL_JJQ",
           "width" : 573
        }
     ],
```

EDIT: It seems that it is only working for HTTP and not HTTPS ... not looking for a work around.

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to developer's guide: https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/photos#place_photo_requests

which suggested you can get the photo by:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CnRtAAAATLZNl354RwP_9UKbQ_5Psy40texXePv4oAlgP4qNEkdIrkyse7rPXYGd9D_Uj1rVsQdWT4oRz4QrYAJNpFX7rzqqMlZw2h2E2y5IKMUZ7ouD_SlcHxYq1yL4KbKUv3qtWgTK0A6QbGh87GB3sscrHRIQiG2RrmU_jF4tENr9wGS_YxoUSSDrYjWmrNfeEHSGSc3FyhNLlBU&key=API_KEY

=-=-=-=-=- edit -=-=-=-=-=
you should not use the `Google Maps API Web Services` on your client side web app, as it violates the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` policy.

the correct way to do it is to use the [Places Library in Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) as it is [shown here](http://jsfiddle.net/dLxqx3n8/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer kaho. Unfortunately my problem is that I need to get the photoreference based on a nearby search first in order to be able to make this call. I am getting results for my search "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=MYAPIKEY" but somehow it seems that I cannot get the contained information as it is a secure connection. At the moment I am trying to find a work around for this. If I find something I will of course post it here.

Comment: you are talking about the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`?

Comment: Hmm as I am pretty new to all this I do not really know what this means. All I want to achieve is getting the first photo_reference from this file: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=AIzaSyA4zkc1dthxoS2a_2vAHUs-a0ZvDmPMMhY Unfortunately as it is ssl sequred the code shown above won't work. I am pretty much stuck and cannot find an answer on how to solve it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Alrighty it is solved now. =) Thanks again for your help. For anyone interested I used an unclean solution in which I first imported the JSON data into a variable in PHP and then used a substring to get my one photo reference.

Answer (score -2):

```
    String response = String.Empty;
    string api = https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CnRtAAAATLZNl354RwP_9UKbQ_5Psy40texXePv4oAlgP4qNEkdIrkyse7rPXYGd9D_Uj1rVsQdWT4oRz4QrYAJNpFX7rzqqMlZw2h2E2y5IKMUZ7ouD_SlcHxYq1yL4KbKUv3qtWgTK0A6QbGh87GB3sscrHRIQiG2RrmU_jF4tENr9wGS_YxoUSSDrYjWmrNfeEHSGSc3FyhNLlBU&key=API_KEY;

    HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(api);
    WebResponse myResp = myReq.GetResponse();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myResp.GetResponseStream());
    reader.ReadToEnd();
    response = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myResp.ResponseUri.AbsoluteUri);

Now you will get image url.
```